# Why doesn't the voltage at the resonance frequency go above the input frequency of a sine wave source?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, frequency, resonance, sine

I have performed a simple RLC parallel circuit experiment to determine the resonance frequency. I used the voltage as the magnitude.

Experimentally, the magnitude at the resonance frequency tops at about 3.8 V. Using LTspice, I obtain the same resonance frequency, but the magnitude there is the same as the input (2 V).

[image: Curve]

[image: Circuit].

Does anyone know what could be the issue? Perhaps I am doing something wrong. The output of the function generator is 2 V out of 50 Ω and it was terminated with a 50 Ω coaxial cable.

Comment: Maybe you used a series RLC, or some other sort?

Comment: nope it was parallel:)

Comment: This question does not have enoughdetails shown. You say 50 Ohm generator impedance, and 50 ohm coax termination (which may or may not have a 50 ohm resistor terminating the coax. It is thus unlclear so far what the exact question is. || Can you please provide enough detail that we can be certain that we are not "talking past each other".  A diagram of th real-world setup and measured voltages may help.

Answer (score 5):

If your real life signal source was set to "2V" on a 50R output, and you didn't terminate it with 50R, it would produce about 4V into that load.

Comment: RF signal generators generally have a 50 ohm output impedance, and are calibrated to produce the correct output into a 50 ohm load (aka termination). They would then produce about twice this voltage into an open circuit (or something close, like 20 kilohms. The reason behind this will become clearer when you study transmission line theory. Meanwhile, add 50R from V1 to GND.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looking forward to learning more about it:)

Comment: Also if I just add 50R between V1 to GND the LTSpice still returns the same diagram which tops at 2V. Sorry I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: In LTSpice, V1 is a perfect voltage source, with zero output impedance. I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: it was in fact terminated by 50R so this is not the reason then...

Comment: @TeodorasPaura I'm a site moderator. || Your comment "it was in fact terminated by 50 R ..." is ambiguous. Do you mean that the signal generator has a 50 ohm resistance in series in the siimulation that you do not show? Or ... ? || I gain the impression that the results you are getting re consistent with  signal generato with 0 ohms series resistance, 4VAC open circuit voltage and 2 VAC terminal voltage when terminated with 50 ohms. || What voltage do you see when the signal generator output is open circuit>

Comment: I have declined a flag on this answer BECAUSE I think that people need to be sure that they are in fact communicating clearly re the circuit elements involved.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon If it is an open circuit, 2 V is observed. When the circuit is connected as shown above the measured voltage is 4 V. The function generator output is 50R and the circuit is terminated with 50R coaxial cable when measuring the voltage, therefore it could not have been 4 V due to the reason presented in this answer (I am describing the real experiment, not the simulation)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon For example, the answer given beneath is just simply wrong and the simulation website is overlooking a very important mistake. I will try to explain it in my own answer...

Comment: @TeodorasPaura when you finish your answer, please let me know by raising a comment such as `@andyaka` etc.. I am interested to know what the very important mistake my calculator is overlooking.

Comment: @TeodorasPaura what exactly does "terminated with 50R coaxial cable" mean? A 50R cable is not a 50R termination ... unless it is infinitely long, or is itself terminated with a 50R resistance. Some other lengths have quite surprising results, at specific frequencies...

Answer (score 1):

> *using LTSpice I obtain the same resonance frequency but the magnitude at it is the same as the input. (2V)*

Yes, the maximum voltage across the parallel LC circuit at resonance equals the voltage applied to the input i.e. to the 20 kΩ resistor. Given that the input voltage is 2 volts, the maximum output voltage can be no higher than 2 volts: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html).

> *Experimentally, the magnitude at the resonance frequency tops at about
> 3.8V.*

I expect you used **a different signal voltage when you tested the real components** experimentally or, you used a different circuit. I cannot be sure because you haven't revealed that circuit.

Comment: Could I be possibly doing something wrong with the LTSpice program? I even double-checked with my lecturer that I was using a sine wave generator with an amplitude of 2 volts. Or was the maximum amplitude supposed to be 4 in real life and that is why i got so close to it?

Comment: In the real circuit, I used all the same components except that I had a sine wave source for the AC and determined different amplitudes using an oscilloscope by varying its frequencies..

Comment: Your LTSpice simulation is correct. I expect your experiment was using a source higher than 2 volts or your circuit was not how you thought it was.

Comment: "I was using a sine wave generator with an amplitude of 2 volts."  Did you _measure_ that voltage with your scope at the same time you measured the tank voltage?  Or did you just _set_ the voltage on a digital signal generator?

Comment: @TimWescott i measured and also checked it

Comment: @TeodorasPaura I'm afraid it's very clear-cut in this type of circuit; it cannot generate an output voltage greater than the input voltage so either the input voltage is bigger than you thought, or you are measuring the output voltage incorrectly or, the circuit you think you have is incorrect (i.e. a series LC circuit for instance).

Comment: AFAIK a resonant LC circuit can exhibit voltage higher than what is applied, and the limit depends on the Q of the components, which mostly depends on ESR and other qualities that dissipate more energy as the voltage rises. In this case it also depends on the resistor driving the circuit.

Comment: Well, I simulated it and indeed the voltage tops out at 2V P-P. At frequencies other than resonance, the voltage is lower.

Comment: @PStechPaul you were right it does exhibit higher voltage than input, but the simulation is wrong, I will go more into detail in my own answer..

Comment: @PStechPaul that is correct. At resonance, the impedance of the L and C together become infinite hence, there is no voltage magnification.

Comment: I think it may be possible to see higher voltages if the driving signal has harmonics (like a square wave). I seem to remember experiencing high voltages in a resonant circuit I built. But it might have been a series resonant circuit where current will approach infinity, just as a parallel resonant circuit driven by a current source will reach high voltages, although limited by the source compliance voltage.

Comment: @PStechPaul a series resonant circuit can create very large voltages. A parallel resonant circuit fed from a voltage source via a resistor cannot produce voltages higher than the input voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes it can, if the resistor is connected in the way that is presented in my simulation and even in this website simulation, that is why the answer is wrong.. I will upload the solution as soon as possible, the mathematics is quite vigorous behind it..

Comment: @TeodorasPaura my answer shows how the resistor, capacitor and inductor are connected hence, my answer cannot be wrong because it matches your circuit. The maths actually is very simple. However, if your "new" circuit is different to what you show in your question then all bets are off in this respect.

Comment: @Andyaka before writing my full derivation I would like to mention that the resistor is not parallel!!! Which change the case and the voltage in this case IS higher than input. Of course if I have a mistake in my calculation and somehow the reading was twice higher by a mistake, I will be glad if you can point it out. Thanks though

Comment: @TeodorasPaura I have no idea what you mean. My resistor (and yours in your question) is in series with the input side i.e. "not parallel" so, that in itself doesn't change anything. Hence I don't understand why you are mentioning that it "change(s) the case". I have no idea what circuit you are considering in your head; I only have the circuit in your question = the circuit in my answer = does not cause a peak higher than the input voltage.